# How to launch a Cordova project with full rebuilding of plugins?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I'm working on a Cordova plugin. As a plugin can't be executed, I'm using a Cordova project to test it. I found that running a Cordova project will not reimport and rebuild plugins, so currently I'm doing this:

```
rmdir \"./plugins/my-plugin\" /q /s
cordova platform remove android
cordova platform add android
cordova run android --device
```

Did I miss something or Cordova really doesn't have a command to fully rebuild everything before running the project?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, cordova will check your `plugins` folder only when adding or updating a plugin or platform. Then it will build and copy the needed plugin(s) into the designated OS in the `platforms` folder.

By your script I assume the source of the plugin is outside of the project folder. So the script you're using should do the work. But if I may give you a better solution would be as follows:

1. Create a Symlink/shortcut of the source folder for your plugin into the `plugins` folder, so you'll not need to remove the folder and stress the disk into copying files everytime you want to run the update.
2. Your "update" script should delete only the installed plugin folder at `platforms/android/platform_www/plugins/my-plugin` and it'll make the update far more quickier than removing and adding the platform again.

Comment: Well, that might make it less painful indeed... Thanks!